# How to make button invisible but it's content should be visible in xaml

Tags: xaml

Below is code for my button, so what properties should I add to make button invisible but content must be visible.

```
<Button x:Name="PART_PreviousButton" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
    Content="&lt;"
    Focusable="False" 
    Opacity="0" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the button Template to have this kind of result.
This link explains it pretty well, the easiest way is to do it with blend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613598.aspx